# Is it correct to use prepare statement in another one?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I decided to try `mysqli::prepare` and I wanted to know if it is valid to use prepare in another prepare as I did:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT mail FROM members WHERE id = ?') or die($mysqli->error);
$stmt->bind_param('i', $db['id']);

$db['id'] = $_SESSION['id'];

$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($db['mail']);

if($stmt->num_rows === 1) {
    $stmt->fetch();

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare('UPDATE members SET pass = ? WHERE id = ?') or die($mysqli->error);
    $stmt->bind_param('si', $db['pass'], $db['id']);

    $db['pass'] = $data['pass'];
    $db['id']   = $_SESSION['id'];

    $stmt->execute();
    echo 'Your password has been changed';
}

$stmt->close();
```

I still don't get the reason why is it better to use `prepare` instead of just `query`. I mean, If I need to get input, and I sanitize it (remove tags and non-allowed special characters and MySQL's `SELECT`, `WHERE`, etc...) before the submission, what's the difference?

Comment: Read about SQL injection

Comment: @Jens I already did

Comment: Then you should know why you should use prepared statements

Comment: @Jens But, SQL injection can be prevented if I don't allow SQL words and characters (such as `'` and `SELECT, WHERE`, etc)

Comment: And how will you provide it? Reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @Jens Regular expressions(?) is not a way?

Comment: @Then write a regex that skip all possible SQL injection attempts

Comment: Handling SQL injections yourself is a stupid idea, use what is already there, it is way more efficient than any method you write.

Comment: @Ian, Jens - Alright, I got it. but what about the main question: what I did was valid? (one statement in another one)

Comment: What do you mean 1 in another? Looks fine...

Comment: @Ian I mean, is it okay to run this? and is it correct to insert `$stmt->close()` after the `if` statement and not inside? Excuse me, I'm new to `prepare` and I don't want to do mistakes

Comment: It sounds very procedural to me. Why are you doing `$stmt->fetch();` and after that, you instantiate `$stmt` again for a new preparation.

Comment: @schellingerht I want to store the mail, In case i'll need it (instead of calling it again)

Answer (score 0):

SQL Injection is the reason to prepare your data before binding it to the query. You have not had injection problem and that is why you cant see the different.
Always use the prepare statement when you are submitting user inputted data to your database, that way you wont worry about escaping individual string.
User can input something like "myUser//?" which can make your query to ignore some portion of your queryString.
Example:
if your website requires username and password, a user can input
-james on the username field
//? on the password field
This can make your query ignore the password field.